# Centering an outer container when inside is left aligned in html

Tags: html, css

I have a bunch of cards on my html page. The container that holds all the cards are left aligned so that when the screen is a smaller size it overflows onto the next row and starts from the far left. However I want to possibly wrap this container around another container that will centre it to the screen. Would appreciate any guidance.

```css
        * {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        body {
            background-color: #0D192B;
            background-size: cover;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            flex-direction: column;
            font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
        }

        .header {
            margin-top: 20px;
            margin-bottom: 40px;
            color: #ffffff;
            font-size: 42px;
            font-family: "Montserrat", -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", "Roboto", "Oxygen", "Ubuntu", "Cantarell", "Fira Sans", "Droid Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
        }

        .center-wrapper {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .card-container {
            display: flex;
            gap: 60px;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            justify-content: flex-start;
            /* justify-content: center; */
            align-items: center;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }

        .card {
            height: 323px;
            width: 320px;
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.06);
            -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
            backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
            border-radius: 8px;
            box-shadow: 20px 20px 22px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            text-align: center;
            transition: transform 0.3s ease;
        }

        .card:hover {
            transform: translateY(-10px);
        }

        .card-img {
            height: 120px;
            width: 120px;
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.06);
            -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
            backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
            border-radius: 50%;
            margin: 30px auto 20px auto;
            transition: transform 0.3s ease;
        }

        .card-img:hover {
            transform: translateY(-10px);
        }

        .card-img img {
            height: 80%;
            border-radius: 100%;
            margin-top: 12px;
        }

        h6 {
            margin: 0;
        }

        .desc {
            text-align: center;
            margin-top: 20px;
        }

        .primary-text {
            color: #d5d5d5;
            font-size: 16px;
            font-weight: 600;
            letter-spacing: 0.7px;
            margin: 5px 0;
        }

        .secondary-text {
            color: #c0c0c0;
            font-weight: 400;
            font-size: 14px;
            letter-spacing: 1px;
            margin: 5px 0;
        }

        button {
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.06);
            -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
            backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
            border: none;
            width: 80%;
            padding: 15px 0;
            border-radius: 5px;
            outline: none;
            transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
        }

        button:hover {
            background-color: rgba(192, 136, 18, 1);
            color: black;
        }

        footer {
            color: white;
            font-size: 14px;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 10px;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;600&display=swap">

</head>


<body>

    <div class="header">
        <h1>Welcome!</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="center-wrapper">
        <div class="card-container">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-img">
                    <img src="1.png" alt="1">
                </div>
                <div class="desc">
                    <h6 class="primary-text">Card 1</h6>
                    <h6 class="secondary-text">Software Company 1</h6>
                </div>
                <button class="primary-text" onclick="window.location.href = '/';">Launch</button>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-img">
                    <img src="2.jpg" alt="2">
                </div>
                <div class="desc">
                    <h6 class="primary-text">Card 2</h6>
                    <h6 class="secondary-text">Software Company 2</h6>
                </div>
                <button class="primary-text" onclick="window.location.href = '/';">Launch</button>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-img">
                    <img src="3.png" alt="3">
                </div>
                <div class="desc">
                    <h6 class="primary-text">Card 3</h6>
                    <h6 class="secondary-text">Software Company 3</h6>
                </div>
                <button class="primary-text" onclick="window.location.href = '/';">Launch</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <footer>
        <p>&copy; Testing Footer</p>
    </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

This currently gives me this output:

[image: current output]

My expected output:

[image: expected output]

I did try justify-content: flex-start and centre on the center-wrapper container but it didn't work

Just to be clear I **DON'T** want the output to be like this:

[image: not correct]

Answer (score 1):

> Use `grid` layout instead `flex` box

You doesn't need any wrapper just change the layout.

```
  .card-container {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill,320px);
        justify-content: center;
        gap:2rem;
   }
```

```css
* {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        body {
            background-color: #0D192B;
            background-size: cover;
            /*display: flex; 
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            flex-direction: column;*/ 
            font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
        }

        .header {
            text-align:center; /* use this*/
            margin-top: 20px;
            margin-bottom: 40px;
            color: #ffffff;
            font-size: 42px;
            font-family: "Montserrat", -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", "Roboto", "Oxygen", "Ubuntu", "Cantarell", "Fira Sans", "Droid Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
        }

        /*.center-wrapper {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }*/

        .card-container {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill,320px);
            justify-content: center;
            gap:2rem;
            padding:0 3rem;
        }

        .card {
            height: 323px;
            width: 320px;
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.06);
            -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
            backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
            border-radius: 8px;
            box-shadow: 20px 20px 22px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            text-align: center;
            transition: transform 0.3s ease;
        }

        .card:hover {
            transform: translateY(-10px);
        }

        .card-img {
            height: 120px;
            width: 120px;
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.06);
            -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
            backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
            border-radius: 50%;
            margin: 30px auto 20px auto;
            transition: transform 0.3s ease;
        }

        .card-img:hover {
            transform: translateY(-10px);
        }

        .card-img img {
            height: 80%;
            border-radius: 100%;
            margin-top: 12px;
        }

        h6 {
            margin: 0;
        }

        .desc {
            text-align: center;
            margin-top: 20px;
        }

        .primary-text {
            color: #d5d5d5;
            font-size: 16px;
            font-weight: 600;
            letter-spacing: 0.7px;
            margin: 5px 0;
        }

        .secondary-text {
            color: #c0c0c0;
            font-weight: 400;
            font-size: 14px;
            letter-spacing: 1px;
            margin: 5px 0;
        }

        button {
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.06);
            -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
            backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
            border: none;
            width: 80%;
            padding: 15px 0;
            border-radius: 5px;
            outline: none;
            transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
        }

        button:hover {
            background-color: rgba(192, 136, 18, 1);
            color: black;
        }

        footer {
            color: white;
            font-size: 14px;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 10px;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;600&display=swap">

</head>


<body>

    <div class="header">
        <h1>Welcome!</h1>
    </div>

   
        <div class="card-container">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-img">
                    <img src="1.png" alt="1">
                </div>
                <div class="desc">
                    <h6 class="primary-text">Card 1</h6>
                    <h6 class="secondary-text">Software Company 1</h6>
                </div>
                <button class="primary-text" onclick="window.location.href = '/';">Launch</button>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-img">
                    <img src="2.jpg" alt="2">
                </div>
                <div class="desc">
                    <h6 class="primary-text">Card 2</h6>
                    <h6 class="secondary-text">Software Company 2</h6>
                </div>
                <button class="primary-text" onclick="window.location.href = '/';">Launch</button>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-img">
                    <img src="3.png" alt="3">
                </div>
                <div class="desc">
                    <h6 class="primary-text">Card 3</h6>
                    <h6 class="secondary-text">Software Company 3</h6>
                </div>
                <button class="primary-text" onclick="window.location.href = '/';">Launch</button>
            </div>

        </div>

    <footer>
        <p>&copy; Testing Footer</p>
    </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Very close, on mobile screen version works well but on desktop version tiles are pushed to the left. Thanks for trying

Comment: what do you mean tiles? pushed

Comment: I have updated the code please check

Comment: Very sorry i mean cards. This is what your code looks like on my screen: https://i.imgur.com/GI6cQnW.png

The container that houses all the cards need to be centred on the page

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I can do. I don't know how many cards you will have in the end, but maybe this approach will help you somehow.

```css
* {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        body {
            background-color: #0D192B;
            background-size: cover;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            flex-direction: column;
            font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
        }

        .header {
            margin-top: 20px;
            margin-bottom: 40px;
            color: #ffffff;
            font-size: 42px;
            font-family: "Montserrat", -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", "Roboto", "Oxygen", "Ubuntu", "Cantarell", "Fira Sans", "Droid Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
        }

    .center-wrapper {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;      
      }

        .card-container {
            display: flex;            
            flex-wrap: wrap;            
            flex-direction: row;            
            row-gap: 40px;   
            width:100%;
        }
           
           
         .card-container > * {           
            flex:1;
          }
         
         .card-area
         {
         text-align:center;
         max-width:50%;
         width: 400px;
         }
         
        .card {           
            height: 323px;
            width: 320px;
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.06);
            -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
            backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
            border-radius: 8px;
            box-shadow: 20px 20px 22px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            text-align: center;
            transition: transform 0.3s ease;
            display:inline-block;
        }

        .card:hover {
            transform: translateY(-10px);
        }

        .card-img {
            height: 120px;
            width: 120px;
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.06);
            -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
            backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
            border-radius: 50%;
            margin: 30px auto 20px auto;
            transition: transform 0.3s ease;
        }

        .card-img:hover {
            transform: translateY(-10px);
        }

        .card-img img {
            height: 80%;
            border-radius: 100%;
            margin-top: 12px;
        }

        h6 {
            margin: 0;
        }

        .desc {
            text-align: center;
            margin-top: 20px;
        }

        .primary-text {
            color: #d5d5d5;
            font-size: 16px;
            font-weight: 600;
            letter-spacing: 0.7px;
            margin: 5px 0;
        }

        .secondary-text {
            color: #c0c0c0;
            font-weight: 400;
            font-size: 14px;
            letter-spacing: 1px;
            margin: 5px 0;
        }

        button {
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.06);
            -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
            backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
            border: none;
            width: 80%;
            padding: 15px 0;
            border-radius: 5px;
            outline: none;
            transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
        }

        button:hover {
            background-color: rgba(192, 136, 18, 1);
            color: black;
        }

        footer {
            color: white;
            font-size: 14px;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 10px;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;600&display=swap">

</head>


<body>

    <div class="header">
        <h1>Welcome!</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="center-wrapper">
        <div class="card-container">
        <div class="card-area">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-img">
                    <img src="1.png" alt="1">
                </div>
                <div class="desc">
                    <h6 class="primary-text">Card 1</h6>
                    <h6 class="secondary-text">Software Company 1</h6>
                </div>
                <button class="primary-text" onclick="window.location.href = '/';">Launch</button>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-area">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-img">
                    <img src="2.jpg" alt="2">
                </div>
                <div class="desc">
                    <h6 class="primary-text">Card 2</h6>
                    <h6 class="secondary-text">Software Company 2</h6>
                </div>
                <button class="primary-text" onclick="window.location.href = '/';">Launch</button>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-area">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-img">
                    <img src="3.png" alt="3">
                </div>
                <div class="desc">
                    <h6 class="primary-text">Card 3</h6>
                    <h6 class="secondary-text">Software Company 3</h6>
                </div>
                <button class="primary-text" onclick="window.location.href = '/';">Launch</button>
            </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <footer>
        <p>&copy; Testing Footer</p>
    </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: In my efforts to solve it I did get to this stage but it overlaps when small. But thanks for trying

Answer (score -1):

One option is to just center it out

```
.card-container {
      display: flex;
      gap: 60px;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
   /*
   justify-content: flex-start; REMOVE IT
   */
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Comment: I tried this out. But it is not what I require. Please see my images above. Your code edit gives me the third image. I require the second image format